# 2019 16" i9 MBP w/CalDigit TS3+. External monitor blanks out intermittently after upgrading to the latest minor Monterey release

Tags: macbook-pro, display, monterey

At seemingly random times, the screen goes black for a couple of seconds. I can still type and when the screen returns whatever I typed is there.

One thing I've noticed is that when it happens, the mouse ends up in the top left corner (which I have setup as the hot corner for screensaver), but it wasn't there when the screen blanked, plus it doesn't go to screensaver.

Anyone else experiencing this? I know it could be a cable or hub issue, but it started happening right after I went from Monterey 12.1 (I think) to 12.4 when I did the upgrade recently.

EDIT: I've moved the corner for screensaver to the top right to see what happens. I'll update this post accordingly

UPDATE: It still happened and the mouse still moved itself to the top left.

Comment: There are optional drivers and firmware updates available at [CalDigit](https://downloads.caldigit.com/). Perhaps these will help.

Comment: I already have the latest firmwire unfortunately. Also the fact that the mouse gets moved when this happens makes me think it's not a hardware issue.